# fetch record(s) based on array element value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named test something like below
    {"_id": ObjectId("ciwhciwiwh686ddd")
     "playerName": "Jon Doe"
      "Player Team": "Team1"
     "points": [
               {"date": "01-01-2018", "score": 145},
               {"date": "01-01-2019", "score": 200}
      ]

```
}
```

Went thru mongoDB official documents and tried following methods

```
db.test.find({"Player Team": "Team1"}, {"points": {"date":"01-01-2018"}})
```

I also tried

```
db.test.find({"Player Team": "Team1"}, {"points.date":"01-01-2018"})
```

I'm getting Unsupported projection option:

Comment: I think I found answer. need to use $elemMatch

Comment: you are getting "Unsupported projection option" error bcs your query is wrong.

Comment: try -------    db.test.find({"Player Team": "Team1", "points": {"date":"01-01-2018"}})

Comment: or ----    db.test.find({"Player Team": "Team1" , "points.date":"01-01-2018"})

Answer (score 0):

The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

db.test.find({"Player Team": "Team1"}, {"points": {$elemMatch {"date":"01-01-2018"}}})